# Was the universe cold before the Big Bang?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, temperature, time, big-bang

I think matter cause something to be hot or cold. So before Big Bang there was no matter in the space so what would have been the temperature of space at that time (if time was even there before Big Bang :).

Comment: there was no space before big bang

Answer (score 3):

There is no universe before the Big Bang, it is the point at which space and time come into existence. There is no "where" that could have a temperature and no "when" you could call before matter. The question is meaningless.

Comment: okay... but a thing would fill into something. so after big bang our universe came into existence but it came into what ?? and if it came into that then there would be something present there.

Comment: @HitmanA7 This is a very hard concept to grasp and it really only becomes clear in some advanced mathematics.  The "simplest" explanation is to read about the [expansion of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe) and [Hubble's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law) but it is not intuitive in an everyday-common-sense way.

Answer (score 0):

All our notions of space and time , of what was there , what happened etc. come from exploration  of the laws of physics, which are in the form they are in our universe i.e. the laws of physics are valid in the domain of our universe.

Questions regarding what happened before the big bang are questions outside the domain of our known laws of physics. It is equivalent to asking what the laws of physics are in another universe.

The best answer is . We do not know. Other universes do not follow our laws of physics and hence, we cannot say anything about them

Comment: okay... but a thing would fill into something. so after big bang our universe came into existence but it came into what ?? and if it came into that then there would be something present there.

Comment: A thing fills into something only inside your room. Because, there is already an empty room there, and then the thing filled into the empty room. But in case of the universe, there was no empty room into which the universe expanded.

Comment: I think you are imagining it wrong. Read the top voted answer  for the following quesion. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point          You will get a better idea about the big bang